# Is there any way to get a new Azure CLI token without logging out?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-authentication

I have a system where the client is using the Azure CLI token to do AA against a service.  the service parses the JWT bearer token obtained send in the authorization header by the client.

The server then checks the group membership to see what groups the client is a part of.

The problem is that if the user is added or removed from a group they need to logout and back in again to have their local CLI include the group membership changes.

Anyone know of an Azure endpoint I could call from the server to get the current group membership?  Or a anything to call on the CLI to get a new token with the updated group memberships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hit MS Graph API using the az cli access token to get the latest group memberships of a user on the service side.

This is the endpoint to hit - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true&$select=displayName

Ref - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-transitivememberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Make sure to pass an access token with Graph as the resource -
az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph

Comment: Interesting, is the graph access token different from the normal token achieved from the CLI?

I ask because we're calling `get_token` on the `AzureCliCredential` class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.azureclicredential?view=azure-python

Comment: Interesting, I am wondering if the problem is that the groups are controlled by a different scope?

I'm reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scopes-oidc

and it claims that it should be getting a new token for the scope but I wonder if the problem is that the group we're interested in isn't tied to that scope?

The Graph scope might be what I'm looking for

Comment: As per the reference that I tagged, you only need User.Read scope to get response from this Graph API. Also, the default resource for which access token is generated in CLI is management.core.windows.net, hence you need to supply the custom graph scope if you'll be using the token to hit graph api.